# Based on a specific number, how to I work out the % increase required, using the % decrease which will be applied, to get back to that number?

Tags: excel, percentage

Example:

$100 is the base number, but a deduction of 9% will be applied.

How do I calculate the % increase required from $100, in order to deduct 9% and get back to $100? I am looking for the calculation not the answer, as the % deducted will be variable.

I am using excel and would prefer in an excel formula if possible, but not necessary, the calculation to find the increase % is enough. thanks

Comment: So multiply by 1.09 or 109/100.

Comment: That isn't correct. 9% of 109 is 9.81. So this would leave me with less than 100.

Comment: The calculation would be: 100/(1-0.09) i.e. `BaseNumber/(1-Deduction Pct)`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula to calculate the value.

[image]

Formula in Calculated Value cell i.e. C2 is:

`=A2/(1-B2)`

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the original amount and y% be the increase %. That means the increased amount will be
x*(100+y)/100
If z% be the decrease then
The decreased amount will be
x*(100-z)/100
If the decrease is to be done on the increased amount then we get
(x*(100+y)/100) * ((100-z)/100) = x
Solving for z we get

z=100y/(100 + y)
Means an increase of x% can be offset by a decrease of z=100y/(100 + y)%

Solving this the other way round
we get y=100z/(100-z)

This means a decrease of 20% will be offset by an increase of
(100 + 100*20/(100-80)) %

For an amount of 200 a 20% decrease will get us 160.
160*(100 + 100*20/(80))/100 will be back to 200.

Just replace x,y, and z with sheet references.